# Groovy equivalent of Scala views

Tags: scala, groovy

I am trying to convert this Scala code to Groovy:

```
val r = BigInt(2).pow(1000).toString.view.map(_.asDigit).sum
```

What is the equivalent of "view" to groovy?

Comment: It seems that there's no `view` equivalent in groovy.

Comment: I wonder if `"abc".iterator()` is lazy?

Comment: @tim_yates no, the str.iterator() creates an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Java8 brings [`chars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) (basically an iterator), which you can reduce over for the sum:

```
groovy:000> 2G.pow(1000).toString().chars().reduce(0){ a,b -> a+b-48 }
===> 1366
```

Or closer to your Scala code (map, sum):

```
groovy:000> 2G.pow(1000).toString().chars().map{ it-48 }.sum()
===> 1366
```

That magic 48 is the ascii for "0".

As a generic answer: Many of the functional methods in groovy tend to realize the results, but Java 8 streams are just as easy to use from Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

```
def result = new BigInteger(2).pow(1000).toString().toCharArray().toList().sum { it - 48 }
```

or

```
def result1 = 2g.pow(1000).toString().toCharArray().toList().sum { it - 48 }
```

Comment: `toCharArray`: "Converts this string to a new character array."; an "more readable" version using `collect` was already voted off.